# using ajax populate dynamic piechart from chartjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, chart.js, pie-chart

Hello there stack overflow programmers, i have a question related to getting data from my database using ajax and display it in piechart from chartjs library. Now i am trying to make dynamic data to be accepted by format within piechart format.

Here is my ajax and its response: ( still it doesn't show my piegraph.  i dont know why)

```
    function getpieclinic() {
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: siteurl+"patients_report/piedataclinic",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess_,
            error: OnErrorCall_
    });

    function OnSuccess_(response) {
      // alert("hi");
            var aData = response.d;
            var arr = [];
            $.each(aData, function (inx, val) {
                var obj = {};
                obj.color = val.color;
                obj.value = val.value;
                obj.label = val.label;
                arr.push(obj);
            });
            var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
            var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(arr);
        }

        function OnErrorCall_(response) {}
}
```

the response of my ajax is these:

```
[{"clinic_name":"Clinic 1","total_checked_up":"4"},{"clinic_name":"Clinic 2","total_checked_up":"0"},{"clinic_name":"Clinic 3","total_checked_up":"0"},{"clinic_name":"Clinic 4","total_checked_up":"0"}]
```

now, i want to make a dynamic format of piechart chartjs data format to be able to display it. this is the default format from the example:

```
var pieChartCanvas = $("#pieChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
    var pieChart = new Chart(pieChartCanvas);
    var PieData = [
      {
        value: 700,
        color: "#f56954",
        highlight: "#f56954",
        label: "Chrome"
      },
      {
        value: 500,
        color: "#00a65a",
        highlight: "#00a65a",
        label: "IE"
      },
      {
        value: 400,
        color: "#f39c12",
        highlight: "#f39c12",
        label: "FireFox"
      },
      {
        value: 600,
        color: "#00c0ef",
        highlight: "#00c0ef",
        label: "Safari"
      },
      {
        value: 300,
        color: "#3c8dbc",
        highlight: "#3c8dbc",
        label: "Opera"
      },
      {
        value: 100,
        color: "#d2d6de",
        highlight: "#d2d6de",
        label: "Navigator"
      }
    ];
    var pieOptions = {
      //Boolean - Whether we should show a stroke on each segment
      segmentShowStroke: true,
      //String - The colour of each segment stroke
      segmentStrokeColor: "#fff",
      //Number - The width of each segment stroke
      segmentStrokeWidth: 2,
      //Number - The percentage of the chart that we cut out of the middle
      percentageInnerCutout: 50, // This is 0 for Pie charts
      //Number - Amount of animation steps
      animationSteps: 100,
      //String - Animation easing effect
      animationEasing: "easeOutBounce",
      //Boolean - Whether we animate the rotation of the Doughnut
      animateRotate: true,
      //Boolean - Whether we animate scaling the Doughnut from the centre
      animateScale: false,
      //Boolean - whether to make the chart responsive to window resizing
      responsive: true,
      // Boolean - whether to maintain the starting aspect ratio or not when responsive, if set to false, will take up entire container
      maintainAspectRatio: true,
      //String - A legend template
      legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"
    };
    //Create pie or douhnut chart
    // You can switch between pie and douhnut using the method below.
    pieChart.Doughnut(PieData, pieOptions);
```

Comment: is this some kind of a homework / project ?

Comment: yes @moáois , a system project in school.

Comment: @moáois thak you for your reply. please help me. i am confused in this code: $.each(aData, function (inx, val) {
                var obj = {};
                obj.color = val.color;
                obj.value = val.value;
                obj.label = val.label;
                arr.push(obj);
            });

Comment: hmm. ohk.. are you getting the response correctly? can you share the actual site url to which you are sending the ajax request ?

Comment: i am only using localhost sir, the response is in the top sir. the response in my querry looks good, but my problem is, converting the response to the format of chartjs piechart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish this in the following way ...

```js
// for demonstration purposes only
// use response.d in real case scenario
var response = [{ "clinic_name": "Clinic 1", "total_checked_up": "10" }, { "clinic_name": "Clinic 2", "total_checked_up": "20" }, { "clinic_name": "Clinic 3", "total_checked_up": "30" }, { "clinic_name": "Clinic 4", "total_checked_up": "40" }]; // response from ajax request

OnSuccess_(response);

function OnSuccess_(response) {
    var pieChartCanvas = $("#pieChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
    var pieChart = new Chart(pieChartCanvas);
    var PieData = [];
  
    // create PieData dynamically
    response.forEach(function(e) {
        var random_color = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
        PieData.push({
            value: e.total_checked_up,
            color: random_color,
            highlight: random_color,
            label: e.clinic_name
        });
    });
  
    var pieOptions = {
        //Boolean - Whether we should show a stroke on each segment
        segmentShowStroke: true,
        //String - The colour of each segment stroke
        segmentStrokeColor: "#fff",
        //Number - The width of each segment stroke
        segmentStrokeWidth: 2,
        //Number - The percentage of the chart that we cut out of the middle
        percentageInnerCutout: 0, // This is 0 for Pie charts
        //Number - Amount of animation steps
        animationSteps: 100,
        //String - Animation easing effect
        animationEasing: "easeOutBounce",
        //Boolean - Whether we animate the rotation of the Doughnut
        animateRotate: true,
        //Boolean - Whether we animate scaling the Doughnut from the centre
        animateScale: false,
        //Boolean - whether to make the chart responsive to window resizing
        responsive: true,
        // Boolean - whether to maintain the starting aspect ratio or not when responsive, if set to false, will take up entire container
        maintainAspectRatio: true,
        //String - A legend template
        legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"
    };
  
    //Create pie or douhnut chart
    // You can switch between pie and douhnut using the method below.
    pieChart.Doughnut(PieData, pieOptions);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="pieChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: wowww. thank you sir. i appreciate your answer. please wait... i'll try this. and also trace to understand